# Filling a big rectangle with small rectangles

Tags: np-complete

There are ***N*** numbers; their values are ***A1, A2, ..., An*** respectively, their sum is ***S***. There is a big rectangle which area is S. You need to draw ***N*** number small rectangle which area is its value.
Requirement:
(1).  The small rectangle must be inside the big rectangle and fill the large rectangle in full(no extra room left);
(2).  No small rectangle can be overlapped;
(3).  Each edge of the big rectangles must contain at least 3 small rectangles edges. 
Find the solution to coordinates of the lower left corner,  width and height of each rectangle.

An example is given in the photo (N = 10)：https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkTFx.png
[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question?